# Help with Magento data-migration-tool 1.9.4.0 to 2.2.25

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, data-migration-tool

I need to migrate data from a installation that uses version 1.9.4.0 to 2.2.5.

I installed data-migration-tool:2.2.5 via composer.

On opensource-to-opensource directory I could not find 1.9.4.0 version so I proceeded with 1.9.3.9 that is the closes versions (but might be the cause of error).

I need to migrate only clients + orders. Products and other details has already been migrated using Magmi.

The migration ran fine for some time but I got the following error:

```
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: adminnotification_inbox Source: 2328 Destination: 4
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: captcha_log Source: 0 Destination: 1
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity Source: 359 Destination: 118
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_datetime Source: 716 Destination: 18
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_decimal Source: 358 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_int Source: 3554 Destination: 829
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_text Source: 1792 Destination: 81
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_varchar Source: 3410 Destination: 802
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_product Source: 185953 Destination: 4791
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_product_index Source: 207304 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity Source: 48152 Destination: 1021
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_datetime Source: 118950 Destination: 9
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_decimal Source: 251368 Destination: 6060
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_int Source: 1256888 Destination: 24376
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery Source: 72695 Destination: 7145
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value Source: 75405 Destination: 7135
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_text Source: 418151 Destination: 2047
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_varchar Source: 1165021 Destination: 20392
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_link Source: 67134 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_link_attribute Source: 7 Destination: 5
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_link_attribute_int Source: 13 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_link_type Source: 5 Destination: 4
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option Source: 13128 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_price Source: 6564 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_title Source: 13132 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_price Source: 170636 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_title Source: 170688 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_value Source: 170657 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_relation Source: 16278 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_attribute Source: 32 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_attribute_label Source: 32 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_super_link Source: 16279 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_website Source: 55782 Destination: 1021
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cataloginventory_stock_item Source: 48152 Destination: 1021
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_block Source: 83 Destination: 38
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_block_store Source: 83 Destination: 38
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_page Source: 120 Destination: 9
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_page_store Source: 120 Destination: 9
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: email_template Source: 11 Destination: 3
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: session Source: 4919 Destination: 270
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: translation Source: 4 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon_aggregated Source: 14010 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon_aggregated_updated Source: 13196 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_eav_attribute_website Source: 0 Destination: 26
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_form_attribute Source: 117 Destination: 84
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_country Source: 246 Destination: 245
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_country_region Source: 511 Destination: 568
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_country_region_name Source: 538 Destination: 568
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_label Source: 7 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_option Source: 11369 Destination: 763
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_option_value Source: 11392 Destination: 763
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_entity_store Source: 7 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_element Source: 52 Destination: 42
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_fieldset Source: 2 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_fieldset_label Source: 2 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_type Source: 5 Destination: 4
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_type_entity Source: 8 Destination: 6
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: newsletter_subscriber Source: 33585 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: newsletter_template Source: 1 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: oauth_consumer Source: 4 Destination: 104
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: oauth_nonce Source: 33 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: oauth_token Source: 7 Destination: 19
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating Source: 2 Destination: 3
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_option Source: 10 Destination: 15
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_option_vote Source: 1506 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_option_vote_aggregated Source: 2210 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_store Source: 4 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event Source: 178178 Destination: 254
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily Source: 659 Destination: 13
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly Source: 586 Destination: 7
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly Source: 586 Destination: 7
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: reporting_module_status Source: 144 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review Source: 753 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review_detail Source: 753 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review_entity_summary Source: 1154 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review_store Source: 1506 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily Source: 97658 Destination: 2
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly Source: 57250 Destination: 2
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly Source: 25162 Destination: 2
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_creditmemo Source: 5635 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_creditmemo_comment Source: 5500 Destination: 0
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_creditmemo_item Source: 6315 Destination: 0

  [Migration\Exception]
  Volume Check failed
```

Any clues?

Thanks !!

Gustavo Ulyssea

Answer (score 0):

The error messages say that the source records on your M1 instance don't match the upgraded one on M2.

If you are ok with those entities being missed. You rerun the data upgrade using -a option, like this:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -r -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml
```

Otherwise, you need to find out why those entities don't match when migrating to M2 and then fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

your database already have some data, migration tool checks that.
you can edit xml mapping files to migrate proper data only. also do not migrate stats like:

```
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event Source: 178178 Destination: 254
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily Source: 659 Destination: 13
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly Source: 586 Destination: 7
[2019-08-28 14:58:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly Source: 586 Destination: 7
```

Comment: Hi ! I confirm that there was content. I tried making this database empty and it worked fine.

Comment: @MagenX, I got a couple of mismatch of entities error, could you please tell me what to be done to correct as I just don't want to ignore them.